Can someone please help to see if FR111 is a real serial number for a 1979 Robinson bmx
I’m trying to figure out if this serial number on a 1979 Robinson is legit it reads FR111 thats it. Can someone please help. Thank you.

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm afraid there is no standard for bicycles serial numbers; if you're sure it's a Robinson, then you might contact them (or their successor company) to see if they can help.  Is there a particular reason you need to know about the serial number?  Mostly you just need to know the specs of the bike for replacement parts, and the make/year will give you that.
